# DNS forwarded vs direct A

Tags: nginx, dns, forwarding, google-cloud-platform

I have a MEAN app in Google Cloud Platform that works correct. When I registered the url in GoDaddy, i entered the public IP on the A record (I couldnt include the 8080 port that works for my app) and website loads correctly on the URL and its showing data from database. Everything seemed to be alright.

But after some use, I found out not all data from database was showing complete. I checked the MEAN app and everything seemed to be correct. For example, I had a list of 10 products in database but only 7 were showing on the web. It seemed to be a problem in the app but it was a big surprise finding out that the complete list of 10 products is showing correctly if I change the DNS to forwarded with mask in GoDaddy control panel.

Does this make any sense for you? Have you experienced such a thing? Im not sure how to solve it coz I dont think I should be using forwarding with mask.

Can you please give me a hint? I dont know much about servers. Maybe its a configuration on the server? Maybe in the DNS?

Comment: Looks like cashing of server responses.

Comment: What really blows my mind is that I think it should either show them all or none at all.... but why would it show just some of them? Also looks like its not refreshing new changes.

Comment: What is the server type?

Comment: Its an nginx server in Google Cloud Platform hosting a Node.JS and Angular app

Comment: I suppose, when response has got, the application saves one to cache. When your send same request again, the response will be taken from cache. When you change a request parameter (URL for example) it forces to send one to the server, therefore the data is updated.

Comment: Sounds right but ive tried on incognito and from other pcs but still showing it differently. Even when i call the api that makes the data request.